# Convert a python nested list in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to convert a nested list to an array and there is something i do not understand.
I got a nested list in my program:

```
listt = [[1986.0,71.2,28.4,13.9,34.7], [1987.0,72.0,30.4,14.0,32.4]]
```

When i use it directly to convert in array:

```
array = np.asarray(listt)
```

i obtain :

```
# out: 
array = [[1.986e+03, 7.120e+01, 2.840e+01, 1.390e+01, 3.470e+01],
        [1.987e+03, 7.200e+01, 3.040e+01, 1.400e+01, 3.240e+01]]
```

And if i manually put each element of my nested list in a new variable, like:

```
# in: 
x = [[1986.0, 71.2, 28.4, 13.9, 34.7], [1987.0, 72.0, 30.4, 14.0, 32.4]]
 
array = np.asarray(x)

# out:  
#        [[1986.    71.2   28.4   13.9   34.7],
#         [1987.    72.    30.4   14.    32.4]]
```

without separated comma. Just want to undestand why in both cases. Thanks

Comment: One is 2D, one is 3D. Are you sure you copy and pasted this stuff properly?

Comment: There is something wrong with your output, your first output should be `[[[1.986.0 , ...]]]` notice the triple brackets? Also even with that difference both the outputs were identical for me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist oups sorry for that , i removed the brackets ( array = np.asarray(listt) )

Comment: @kinshukdua when i removed the first value in each nested list (ex: 1986.0 , 1987.0) , i obtained a perfect array like i wanted . But i still do not undestand why these values had an impact on the result

Comment: It has nothing to do with it.  Compare the output of `str(array)` and `repr(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are able to get the output like you show last, i.e. array without the separating comma. I get the following. I don't remember ever having seen a list of lists without a separating comma.

```
In[4]: x = [[1986.0, 71.2, 28.4, 13.9, 34.7], [1987.0, 72.0, 30.4, 14.0, 32.4]]
       array = np.asarray(x)
       array


Out[4]:array([[1986. ,   71.2,   28.4,   13.9,   34.7],
       [1987. ,   72. ,   30.4,   14. ,   32.4]])
```

Comment: ndarrays will display without commas if you use their `__str__` instead of their `__repr__`.  Compare `print(array)` versus `print(repr(array))` or just `array` at the REPL like you did.  None of the rest has anything to do with anything.

Comment: @MattiH and yet we wrote the same thing but without a comma. and when i ask for the type ```type(array)``` from the variable, i get ( numpy.ndarray)

Comment: @Iguananaut oooh i see,  you are right. Thank you so much